# How to convert OpenCascade Pixmap into OpenCV Mat format?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, converters, opencascade

I am working with the OpenCascade Sample Project and I need to extract an 2D Snapshot of the 3DViewer Scene and convert it into the Opencv Mat format. 
I tried the code below and if I use imshow to display the snapshot, i'll get a complete black view. The PixMap is a 3-Channel RGB image by default.

```
Image_PixMap img;
getViewer()->ActiveView()->ToPixMap(img, 1024, 1024);
cv::Mat* mat_img = new cv::Mat(1024, 1024, CV_8UC3);
img.InitWrapper(Image_Format_RGB, mat_img->ptr(), 1024, 1024);
```

```
Standard_EXPORT virtual bool InitWrapper (Image_Format thePixelFormat,
                                            Standard_Byte*       theDataPtr,
                                            const Standard_Size  theSizeX,
                                            const Standard_Size  theSizeY,
                                            const Standard_Size  theSizeRowBytes = 0);
```

```
 Standard_Boolean ToPixMap (Image_PixMap& theImage,
                             const Standard_Integer theWidth,
                             const Standard_Integer theHeight,
                             const Graphic3d_BufferType& theBufferType     = Graphic3d_BT_RGB,
                             const Standard_Boolean      theToAdjustAspect = Standard_True,
                             const V3d_StereoDumpOptions theStereoOptions  = V3d_SDO_MONO)
```

Comment: Is there an API to convert the PixMap object to 1-D or 2D array?

Comment: There is a method Data() which returns a 2D Array of type Standard_Byte. But All Values within the Array are zero. So I think there is a problem with the topixmap and not with the wrapper.

Comment: Are you sure that all the values are `0`. It may be possible that first freq values of that matrix are `0`. If really all the values are `0`, then I think it needs some more debuggin.

Comment: First thanks for help! Besides, I use already getViewer()->ActiveView()->Dump(), which stores the snapshot image into a file. This works fine. Dump should be the same operations as toPixmap (Documentation Opencascade). I convert Image to Byte array and iterate through all pixels and test on max value as follows.

Comment: `const Standard_Byte* bytes_img = img.Data();
 Standard_Byte maxb = bytes_img[0, 0];;
 for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
   if (bytes_img[i, j] > maxb) {
    maxb = bytes_img[i, j];
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: I think i found the problem: The Wrapper and ToPixMap works fine already, but the loaded BrepFile isnt captured by ToPixMap because of its AIS_Shape format.

Comment: Good to know that you have solved it.